# Why javascript variable get reflects on ng-model change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I declare variable object globally, and assigning it on `http` call which will run when angular controller loads, Then I'm assigning this object values to angular scope variable and retrieving it in `ng-model`s. On some button click when I change one of `ng-model` values then it reflects back to `Javascript` global variable. Why?

**This is my `view` page**

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="Edit()" value="Edit" />
<form name="myEditUserForm" novalidate>
<input type="text" ng-model="Info.Name" required ng-blur="Change()">
<input type="text" ng-model="Info.MobileNo" required ng-blur="Change()">
<input type="text" ng-model="Info.Email" required ng-blur="Change()">
<input type="text" ng-model="Info.Gender" required ng-blur="Change()">
<input type="submit" ng-click="Update()" value="Save Changes" />
 </form>
```

**This is my `Angularjs` code**

```
app.controller('SomeController', function ($scope, $http) {
 var someList = {};
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/Dashboard/GetData',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
    }).then(function (response) {
        someList = {
            Name: response.data.Name,
            MobileNo: response.data.MobileNo,
            Email: response.data.Email,
            Gender: response.data.Gender
        };
    });

$scope.Edit = function () {
        $scope.Info = someList;
    };
$scope.Change= function () {
        console.log($scope.UpdateProfile.Email, tenantList.Email);
        if ($scope.Info.Email != someList.Email) {
            alert('changed');
        }
    };
```

I want to get same data from someList to which I assinged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in javascript, objects are mutable and javascript shares references between objects when we assign one object to another. Before I make you understand what is mutability, let's share the concept of reference.

When you create an object / array (array is an object in javascript), what happens? A new state is being created. (Memory allocation to a specific object)

```
let obj = {} // javascript object
let arr = [1,2,3] // javascript object
```

let's assign `obj` into another variable.

```
let obj1 = obj;
```

now add some attributes in `obj1` variable.

```
obj1.first_name = 'John'
obj1.last_name = 'Doe'
obj1.age = 30;
console.log(obj1)
console.log(obj)
```

what's the output?

```
age: 30
first_name: "John"
last_name: "Doe"
```

twice, right? It's because, `obj1` is pointing `obj` means `obj1` is holding only the reference of `obj` variable. So, when we change anything in `obj1`, it's changing the referred variable, `obj`.

now, the mutable part. A mutable object is an object whose state can be changed after creation of the object.

By mutability, it means the memory occupied by the variable will not be changed but the value can changed. So, when we share references of one mutable object, all the referred variables will be changed when we change one of them.

```
let x = ['foo', 'bar'];
let y = x; // y is holding the reference of x

x.push('baz')

console.log(x); // ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
console.log(x === y) // true
```

So, what to do now? If you want the global variable to remain unchanged, you can copy the variable into another, copy will create new state rather than sharing the same memory between the objects. use angular.copy() or use lodash javascript library.

Answer (score 1):

You should take copy of of global veriable in your local scope

Example 
$scope.Info = angular.copy(someList);

Comment: but its copying without using angular.copy...

Comment: @dawoodabbas Do you want a good solution, or not?

Comment: @dawoodabbas if you copy it without using angular.copy it will impact globally whenever your change ng-modal.
angular.copy just make copy of given object and change in local scope